# How to check every value in array within a range using spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, presto

I hope to filter on an array column to check whether every value in array is greater than 10 or smaller than 5, which is just like usage of `cardinality(filter(col, x -> x < 5 or x >10)) > 0` in `presto`. Is it possible to achieve it with pure spark sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use forall function to achieve this

below is sample filter

```
df.filter(F.expr("forall(arr, x -> x<5 or x>10)"))
```

Here I am assuming arr is column name inside dataframe df where each value should either be less than 5 or greater than 10

Details of forall [here](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/forall.html)

Comment: Can you provide me with the full example of using the 'forall' function with proper imports. I imported org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr. What else do I have to import to make it work? I am getting an error like forall is not a registered function in the database.